# kafka.common.errors.UnknownProducerIdException

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We are getting the below exception on the producer logs. Could you please let us know what causing the issue.

```
[2021-02-07 09:38:47,927] ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=1] Error processing append operation on partition *Topicname*-1 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownProducerIdException: Found no record of producerId=68444 on the broker. It is possible that the last message with the producerId=68444 has been removed due to hitting the retention limit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given it is most likely that you are getting this Exception as commented in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/protocol/Errors.java#L275):

> "This exception is raised by the broker if it could not locate the producer metadata associated with the producerId in question. This could happen if, for instance, **the producer's records were deleted because their retention time had elapsed.** Once the last records of the producerId are removed, the producer's metadata is removed from the broker, and future appends by the producer will return this exception."

You are seeing this error because the last offset your producer created has been removed from the topic due to the cleanup policy of the topic. You could change the producer configuration `client.id` to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes we are receing the same exception as mentioned by you

Comment: Yes, correct wat causing the issue here ? and how to avoid such kind of exceptions?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  we are keeping the topic retention period as 3 months